# How to use trapz to calculate a triple integral on a spherical harmonic?

Tags: matlab

I have a combination of spherical harmonics.

[image: equation 1]

Because spherical harmonics are an orthogonal basis, we can say:

[image: equation 2]

Now, I have a function that gives me a spherical harmonic, which gives a spherical harmonic matrix. (the famous spharm4)

First, I want to check if the Y_6^2 is normalized (the integral should be equal to zero) using trapz. How can a 3D integral be done with trapz function using spherical coordinates?

After that, I want to find the coefficient b using eq(2), but I still can’t understand how to use the trapz function correctly and multiply the matrices.

Any help would be appreciated.

Function that gives me a spherical harmonic:

```
function varargout=plm2spec(lmcosi,norma,in,ot)
% [sdl,l,bta,lfit,logy,logpm]=PLM2SPEC(lmcosi,norma,in,ot)
%
% Calculates the power spectrum of real spherical harmonic
% sine and cosine coefficients contained in the matrix 'lmcosi' which is
% of the standard form that can be plotted by PLM2XYZ and PLOTPLM.
%
% INPUT:
%
% lmcosi               Spherical harmonic coefficients [l m Ccos Csin]
% norma                1 multiplication by (l+1) 
%                          This gives the mean-square value of the
%                          gradient of a potential in Schmidt-harmonics
%                      2 division by (2*l+1) [default]
%                          This gives the proper power spectral density
%                          as we've come to know it
%                      3 none, i.e. a scaling factor of 1
% in                   Index to minimum degree to consider for the spectral fit [defaulted]                 
% ot                   Index to maximum degree to consider for the spectral fit [defaulted]                 
%
% OUTPUT:
%
% sdl                  Spectral density: energy per degree
% l                    Degree
% bta                  Spectral slope of loglog(l,sdl)
% lfit,logy            Spectral line plot given by loglog(lfit,logy)
% logpm                Error on spectral line plot given by
%                      loglog(lfit,logpm)
%
% SEE ALSO: MTVAR
%
% EXAMPLE:
%
% [sdl,l,bta,lfit,logy,logpm]=plm2spec(fralmanac('EGM96'));
%
% SEE ALSO: ACTSPEC
%
% The normalization by (2l+1) is what's required when the spherical
% harmonics are normalized to 4pi. See DT p. 858. A "delta"-function then
% retains a flat spectrum. See Dahlen and Simons 2008.
% See papers by Hipkin 2001, Kaula 1967, Lowes 1966, 1974, Nagata 1965
% (Lowes, JGR 71(8), 2179 [1966])
% (Nagata, JGeomagGeoel 17, 153-155 [1965])
%
% Last modified by fjsimons-at-alum.mit.edu, 03/18/2020

defval('norma',2)
lmin=lmcosi(1);
lmax=lmcosi(end,1);

pin=0;
for l=lmin:lmax
  clm=shcos(lmcosi,l);
  slm=shsin(lmcosi,l);
  pin=pin+1;
  sdl(pin)=clm(:)'*clm(:)+slm(:)'*slm(:);
end

switch norma
  case 1 
    normfac=(lmin:lmax)+1;
  case 2
    normfac=1./(2*(lmin:lmax)+1);
  case 3 
    normfac=1;
    disp('Not further normalized')
  otherwise
    error('No valid normalization specified')
end

% disp(sprintf('Normalization %i',norma))
sdl=normfac.*sdl;
sdl=sdl(:);

% Figure out the range over which to make the fit
l=lmin:lmax; 
l=l(:);
if lmin==0
  defval('in',3);
elseif lmin==1
  defval('in',2);
else
  defval('in',1);
end
defval('ot',lmax)
lfit=l(in:ot);

if nargout>=3
  % Calculate spectral slope
  [bt,E]=polyfit(log10(lfit),log10(sdl(in:ot)),1);
  bta=bt(1);
  [logy,loge]=polyval(bt,log10(lfit),E);
  logy=10.^logy;
  logpm=[logy./(10.^loge) logy.*(10.^loge)];
else
  [bta,lfit,logy,logpm]=deal(NaN);
end
```

Comment: Disclaimer: this is a bit beyond my mathematical wherewithal. But, Matlab has a triple integral function: https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral3.html. I believe the trapezoidal method is only working on 2d space. I am not sure how `integral3` would work in a spherical coordinate system. You may have to map between that and cartesian space. Looks like the Phase Array Toolbox cand do this: https://au.mathworks.com/help/phased/ug/spherical-coordinates.html, or else you can do the equations yourself.

Comment: thank you for the answer.
Actually, I solved it myself.
If anyone in the future wants to use what I did. here it is:
https://pastebin.com/xLbWBtTA

Comment: @EylonVakrat If that is a solution to your problem can you add it as an answer here rather than a link in a comments?  Comments get deleted and links rot.